# Joomla uxepected error , with main menu...

Tags: php, html, joomla, menu, program-entry-point

Yesterday I tried to upload my joomla website(whitch works fine) on web host, I did it successful but I have one basic problem. When I type my domain, my home page works fine but the other options on main menu for example "about us" display an error page(which pop up an error page from web host).

I did my reasearch on back-end and i found this when u put a link like "learn more" with about us path, it works fine. That's happenning because of different url call, on main menu about us url is like "my_site.com/about-us" and it isn't work , but the link has url like this "my_site.com/index.php/about-us" and it works fine.

Any idea how can I fix this or how can I edit url link on main menu ?
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try rebuild menu. Go menu->main menu choose all links and click rebuild button on top menubar.

Comment: Also if there's link with /index.php/ you should turn off SEF settings in configuration, else if you want to links work without index.php you should turn on SEF settings and rename htaccess.txt to .htaccess